# How can I calculate correlation within sub-groups of my sample in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am analyzing the results of a survey and I have 2 arrays that I am calculating the correlation for in Excel now that is easy enough, but how I can calculate the correlation for sub-groups that are scattered in the array without doing it manually. for example, I want to calculate the correlation between the 2 variables for males between 15-25 rather than for the whole sample

What I already tried was that I sorted the sample based on the needed dimension meaning that I would sort the whole sample by age so that the data would follow each other instead of being scattered, but this takes time, and can't work for 2 variables such as age and gender

Comment: I use the correl function between the 2 arrays, and unfortunately I can't share the sheet due to privacy of data, but it is a regular sheet with 2 arrays for correlation and the each element in the array have defining characteristics such as age,gender,etc

Comment: yes I mean =CORREL()

Comment: Then please post some mock data showing us what you are working with

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
=CORREL(QUERY(A2:C, "select A where B='15-20' and C='F'", 0),
        QUERY(D2:F, "select D where E='15-20' and F='F'", 0))
```

or something like this:

```
=CORREL(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B="15-20", C2:C="F"),
        FILTER(D2:D, E2:E="15-20", F2:F="F"))
```

but this would work only if you would have equal matrix from those two arrays... the issue with `CORREL` function is that it needs equal-sized range, but when you `FILTER` it or `QUERY` it then output ranges will vary...

then you can try this:

```
=IFERROR(CORREL(QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='15-20' and Col3='F'", 0),
               {QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='15-20' and Col3='F'", 0);
                TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀",
                COUNTA(QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='15-20' and Col3='F'", 0))-
                COUNTA(QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='15-20' and Col3='F'", 0))),"♀"))}),
         CORREL(QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='15-20' and Col3='F'", 0),
               {QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='15-20' and Col3='F'", 0);
                TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀",
                COUNTA(QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='15-20' and Col3='F'", 0))-
                COUNTA(QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='15-20' and Col3='F'", 0))),"♀"))}))
```

[image]

**note:** sadly, even this has own limitations...

and for maximum comfort you can do this with it:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(CORREL(QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&H9&"' and Col3='"&H10&"'", 0),
               {QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&I9&"' and Col3='"&I10&"'", 0);
                TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀",
                COUNTA(QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&H9&"' and Col3='"&H10&"'", 0))-
                COUNTA(QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&I9&"' and Col3='"&I10&"'", 0))),"♀"))}),
         CORREL(QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&I9&"' and Col3='"&I10&"'", 0),
               {QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&H9&"' and Col3='"&H10&"'", 0);
                TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("♂♀",
                COUNTA(QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&I9&"' and Col3='"&I10&"'", 0))-
                COUNTA(QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&H9&"' and Col3='"&H10&"'", 0))),"♀"))})),
 IFERROR(CORREL(QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&H9&"' and Col3='"&H10&"'", 0),
                QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&I9&"' and Col3='"&I10&"'", 0)),
         CORREL(QUERY({D2:F}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&I9&"' and Col3='"&I10&"'", 0),
                QUERY({A2:C}, "select Col1 where Col2='"&H9&"' and Col3='"&H10&"'", 0))))
```

[image]

## [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fc3xWof5XafJv453Mk2pmMf5n0UfoO-f1zRV9eI4fuw/edit#gid=1748363005)

Comment: I decided to just do it with pandas, it was much easier